# Restriction of translation on an abelian variety to a subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-forms, abelian-varieties

Let $A/\mathbb{C}$ be an abelian variety, and let $X\subset A$ be a closed integral subvariety. Assume that $a\in A$ is such that $T_a(X)\subset X$, where $T_a$ is the translation on $A$ by $a$. Does the restriction $T_a:X\to X$ induce the identity on $H^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$ by pullback global forms on $X$?

Comment: No. Take a curve $D$ of genus $>1$ and consider a connected non-trivial unramified abelian covering $C$ of it. By unramified class field theory, this arises by base-change (restriction) from a finite isogeny of abelian varieties $A\to{\rm Jac}(D)$. The curve $C$ is then stabilised in $A$ by some $T_a$, where $a$ is a torsion point of $A$. Now by the geometric Lefschetz trace formula for $T_a|_C$, we have $${\rm Trace}(T_a^*|_C:H^0(C,\Omega^1_C)\to H^0(C,\Omega^1_C))-1=0,$$ so that $T_a^*|_C$ cannot be the identity (since the genus of $C$ is $>1$).

Comment: Nice question, though!

Comment: Dear @DamianRössler, Thank you so much for your nice example!

Comment: @Damian You should promote this to an answer. :)